# ¿Cómo convertir datos en porcentajes y en dolares?

Tags: php

Tengo una variable denominada `$poits` la cual tiene valores numéricos, de aquella variable necesito mostrar sus valores en porcentaje entre el `1` al `100%`, la cual la condición para llegar al `100%` esa variable debe tener un valor de `1000` (mil) puntos, para llegar al `100%`.

De esa misma variable necesito otra opción de poder pasar a dolares, la condición es que si esa variable tiene el valor de `1000` (mil), esta imprima una ganancia de `$5.00` dolares, pero si tiene otro valor que vaya mostrando cuanto va generando, por decir si solo tiene un valor de `30`, este muestre en dolares el porcentaje me imagino por decir `$0.00012` para `$5.00`.

Mi idea es mostrar un gráfico con los porcentajes, y a la vez mostrarle sus ganancias conforme al gráfico.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Intenta procesando tus valores mediante regla de tres simple y guarda tus cálculos en un array asociativo:

```
  /* Regla de tres simple para abmso cálculos
   * 1000 = $5 = 100%
   * 30   = $x = n% 
   */

  //base
  $base = 1000;
  //ganancia maxima
  $max_ganancia = 5;

  //valor
  $points = 1000;

  // cálculo de porcentaje y ganancia
  $porcentaje = $points * 100 / $base;
  $ganancia = $points * $max_ganancia / $base;

  //poniendo dos decimales a la ganancia
  $ganancia = number_format( $ganancia, 2 );

  echo $points." => ".$porcentaje."% - $".$ganancia;
```

Aquí el [**demo**](https://ideone.com/tZmfrT)

Comment: No entiendo cómo funciona, los puntos son obtenidos fijamente desde una variable por decir este usuario tiene `$points = 300;` este valor fijo no funciona https://ideone.com/oWaAsy

Comment: La vriable `$points` tiene los valores, yo necesito obtener los datos individuales porcentajes apartes, ganacinas apartes desde los datos que tenga la variable $points ahora me acabo de encontrar un ejemplo en la web, de esta manera así individual ideone.com/Qq8jLT en ese caso, es el de porcentajes de esa misma manera necesito obtener las ganancias de manera individual.

Comment: Si, porque los puntos totales de `x` usuarios son contabilizados mediante esa variable, y de esa forma como la has empleado como daría yo  uso de ella???

Comment: Si así, pero está mal el cálculo, solo si el usuario tiene 1000 puntos gana 5 dólares, ahora le puesto el valor de 1000 y este usuario tiene ganado 1000 dólares https://ideone.com/W9ZsdA

Comment: Jaja no eso me inventé por decir, pero si necesito que se agregué las decimales, de $5 a $5.00 y de $10 a: $10.00 y así sucesivamente, puedes agregar ese último detallé por favor :)

Comment: listo edite la respuesta, para lo delos decimales se usa number_format

Comment: No funciona https://ideone.com/yCQwb9 debe ser `$10.00` no todo esto `$1,000.00` aquí si muestra los resultado de dolares correctos https://ideone.com/sDbINd pero con lo que has agregado no va bien

Comment: Tienes razon, estaba haciendo una multiplicacion inncesaria, ya lo arregle, revisa https://ideone.com/tZmfrT

Answer (score 2):

Podría ser así:

```
    //Base de Puntos
$base = 1000;
//Ganancia por cada 1000
$ganancia = 5;


//Puntos del Usuario
$puntos = 3000;

//Con esta modificacion el Sistema otorga una ganancia de 5 dólares solo por cada 1000 puntos ganados
if($puntos%$base==0){
    $porcentaje = ($puntos / $base) * 100;
}else{
    $b = $puntos / $base;
    $p = explode(".", $b);
    $porcentaje = (($base * $p[0]) / $base) * 100;
}

//Dinero ganado al momento
$gan = ($ganancia * $porcentaje) / 100;

echo "<li>Puntos Obtenidos: {$puntos} de {$base}</li>";
echo "<li>Porcentaje: {$porcentaje}% de 100%</li>";
echo "<li>Ganancia al Momento: us$ {$gan}</li>";
```

Muestra: [Ver Muestra](https://ideone.com/CrEwJE)

Ese código si el usuario obtiene mas de mil puntos, le calcula su ganancia exponencialmente, esta simple pero creo es lo que necesitas para orientarte.

Comment: Puedes revisar la edición de mi respuesta a ver si la versión anterior es la que buscas o esta nueva que coloque. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

segun entiendo, lo que necesitas es algo como diferir cuanto debe ganar la persona por cada punto obtenido teniendo como tope `100` puntos y `5,00` dolares, entonces debe ir de estar forma:

```
<?php 
  //damos valor tope al porcentaje
  $tope=1000;
                      //sacamos el 1 %
  $un_porcentaje = $tope - (1000 * 0.01);

  //asignamos valor tope de cada 1000
  $dolar = 5,00;

  //sacamos el valor induvidual de cada punto
  $valor = $dolar / $tope;

  //multiplicamos el valor individual de ganancia por la cantidad de puntos
  $ganancia = $un_porcentaje * $valor;

echo  $ganancia;

 ?>
```

espero te sirva de mucho bro y la marques XD... ReNiceCode...

Comment: por eso bro... si necesitas saber cuanto porcentaje y valor tiene 30 puntos pues solo multiplicas `$un_porcentaje * 30` y listo

Comment: bueno, es que `5,00` no puede tener "," debes poner el "."

Comment: disculpame bro, pero debe mirar bien el errores de sintaxis... falta una `n` en la varaible

Comment: Yo creo que no fui claro en mi pregunta, donde va mi variable que tiene los valores, yo necesito obtener los datos individuales porcentajes apartes, ganacinas apartes desde los datos que tenga la variable `$points` ahora me acabo de encontrar un ejemplo en la web, de esta manera así individual https://ideone.com/Qq8jLT en ese caso, es el de porcentajes de esa misma manera necesito obtener las ganancias de manera individual.

Comment: Bueno, la logica esta ahi, solo era cuestion de implementarla, ya quedo ?

Answer (score 0):

Valores

```
$tope = 1000;
$topeValor = 5;
$poits = 180;
```

Para calcular el porcentaje

```
$porcentaje  =   $poits / $tope; // Esto te devuelve el % en base a 1 es decir: 0,18;   
$sobre100 = $porcentaje * 100; // Esto te devuelve le % sobre 100: 18%
```

Para calcular cuanto es en dolares, basta con multiplicar cuanto es el maximo "5" con su porcerntaje en base a 1, es decir :   5 x 0,18 = 0,9 dolares

```
$dolares = $porcentaje * $topeValor;
```